# How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for flask method view?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a flask MethodView as follows

```py
class Ping(MethodView):
    """
    Ping point implementation
    """

    def get(self) -> Response:
        """
        Checks the server's health
        :return: a json as status = 200
        """
        return jsonify(status=200)
```

I want to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for this end-point.

```
def create_app() -> Flask:
    """
    Creates the flask application.
    :return: returns an app instance.
    """

    app: Flask = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    # db config
    app.config["db"] = os.environ.get("APP_DB_NAME")
    app.config["host"] = os.environ.get("APP_DB_HOST")
    app.config["password"] = os.environ.get("APP_DB_PASSWORD")
    app.config["port"] = os.environ.get("APP_DB_PORT")
    app.config["user"] = os.environ.get("APP_DB_USER")

    # secret key config
    app.config.from_mapping(SECRET_KEY=os.environ.get("SECRET"))

    add_urls(app)

    return app


def add_urls(app: Flask) -> None:
    """
    Add urls to app
    :param app: Flask app instance
    """

    # TODO: Declare end-points in a dictionary and iterate.
    app.add_url_rule(
        f"{END_POINT}/ping", view_func=Ping.as_view("ping")
    )
```

The `return jsonify()` method does not have a way to pass headers. How to set header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the Flask-Cors package
2. And import it as:-
   from flask_cors import CORS

   In create_app() method, after you initializes Flask application that is,

   `app: Flask = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)`
3. Declare this line -> CORS(app)